# change column value based on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas

I've seen a lot of posts similar but none seem to answer this question:

I have a data frame with multiple columns. Lets say A, B and C

I want to change column A's value based on conditions on A, B and C

I've got this so far but not working.

```
df=df.loc[(df['A']=='Harry') 
                   & (df['B']=='George') 
                   & (df['C']>'2019'),'A']=='Matt'
```

So if A is equal to Harry, and B is equal to George and C is greater than 2019, then change A to Matt

Anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are really close, assign value `Matt` to filtered `A` by boolean masks:

```
df.loc[(df['A']=='Harry') & (df['B']=='George') & (df['C']>'2019'),'A'] = 'Matt'
```

Comment: It worked!!! thanks a lot for helping. I've been staring at that for hours. I'll accept answer once the time limit has passed. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['A'] = np.where((df['A']=='Harry') & (df['B']=='George') & (df['C']>'2019'), 'Matt', df['A'])
```